# Remove elements from input Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension, haskell-platform

I want to make the function `remove :: String -> Char -> String`
which removes all instances of the character in the second argument
from the string in the first argument. For example:

`remove "ab cd ef" ' ' == "abcdef"`

`remove "ab cd cf" 'c' == "ab d f"`

What I have so far is:

```
remove (x:xs) y 
     | x == y     = xs
     | otherwise  = x : remove xs y
```

This only removes one element, e.g. if I write `remove  "ab cd ef" ' '`
it prints out `"abcd ef"` and not `"abcdef"`.

I need to make one function using recursion and another one using list comprehension.

Comment: You have to recurse in _both_ cases, otherwise you'll remove only the first instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As chi pointed out in the comments, you need to use recursion in both branches or you'll end up only removing the first instance.

For completeness here is the correct code:

```hs
remove [] _ = []
remove (x:xs) y
     | x == y     = remove xs y
     | otherwise  = x : remove xs y
```

If you do not include the `[]` case then you will get an error about pattern matching -- this is because when you match the pattern `(x:xs)` you are assuming that the array has length of >= 1 for `x` to be defined. If you think of lists like `data List a = Cons a (List a) | Empty`, then any functions that take a list must pattern match over the `Cons` and the `Empty` constructors. Obviously, if you have an empty string there's nothing to remove so `[]` maps to `[]` for all `y`.

If you want list comprehension as well, recognise that list comprehension is `map` and `filter` combined. We don't want to change the characters which `map` allows us to do, only to filter out the ones which match `y`.

The syntax `[f x | x <- xs, predicate x]` means "take every `x` from `xs` where the expression `predicate x` is `True`, and return a list of expressions `f x`. The `f x` is the `map` part, the `predicate x` is the filter part.

Thus we can write:

```hs
remove xs y = [x | x <- xs, x /= y]
```

Note here that we don't pattern match the list value constructors, so we don't need two cases. The `x <- xs` part simply means we get `[]` if the input list is empty. We've also used `x` or `id x` instead of `f x`, and our predicate is `x /= y`.

Also FYI the `template-haskell` tag isn't necessary here, that's a metaprogramming language extension.

Comment: Thank you! This gives me "Non-exhaustive patterns in function remove". Is my type signature wrong? (I removed the template now :) )

Comment: @Mali99 ah, my bad. I forgot the empty list case, added now

Comment: Do you happen to have a suggestion on how I can use list comprehension in this function? :) @Oliver

Comment: @Mali99 yes, I've added that as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer has helped me so much! Thank you :)